# SQL Query Microsoft Access - change horizontal field to vertical field

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need help with access SQL Query.
I create view in access using 4 table, my problem show when I want to change some field into vertical. I know if two matrix but if more than it I can't.

This is my looks like before change

```
|DataKioskID | KioskName   | YearFiscal | MonthReport | ProductID | ProductName | Sales | Stock |
|AB0101061501| Sarana Tani |       2015 |           6 |       P15 |     Advanta |     56|     12|
|AB0101061501| Sarana Tani |       2015 |           6 |       P16 |     Advanta |     23|     15|
|AB0101061501| Sarana Tani |       2015 |           6 |       P02 |     Advanta |     14|     12|
|AB0102061501| TaniLestari |       2015 |           6 |       P02 |     Advanta |     15|     14|
|AB0102061501| TaniLestari |       2015 |           6 |       P15 |     Advanta |     12|     15|
|AB0102061501| TaniLestari |       2015 |           6 |       P16 |     Advanta |     14|     23|
```

code :

```
SELECT Data_Kiosk_Header.DataKioskID, Master_Kiosk.KioskName, Data_Kiosk_Header.YearFiscal
, Max(Data_Kiosk_Header.MonthReport) AS monthReport
, Max(IIf(Data_Kiosk_Detail.ProductID='P15',Data_Kiosk_Detail.Sales,0)) AS Advanta_Sales
, Max(IIf(Data_Kiosk_Detail.ProductID='P16',Data_Kiosk_Detail.Sales,0)) AS Agro_Sales
, Max(IIf(Data_Kiosk_Detail.ProductID='P02',Data_Kiosk_Detail.Sales,0)) AS P12_Sales
, Max(IIf(Data_Kiosk_Detail.ProductID='P15',Data_Kiosk_Detail.Stocks,0)) AS Advanta_Stocks
, Max(IIf(Data_Kiosk_Detail.ProductID='P16',Data_Kiosk_Detail.Stocks,0)) AS Agro_Stocks
, Max(IIf(Data_Kiosk_Detail.ProductID='P02',Data_Kiosk_Detail.Stocks,0)) AS P12_Stocks
FROM Master_Kiosk 
INNER JOIN (Data_Kiosk_Header INNER JOIN (Data_Kiosk_Detail 
INNER JOIN Master_Product ON Data_Kiosk_Detail.ProductID = Master_Product.ProductID) ON Data_Kiosk_Header.DataKioskID = Data_Kiosk_Detail.DataKioskID) ON Master_Kiosk.kioskid = Data_Kiosk_Header.KioskName
GROUP BY Data_Kiosk_Header.DataKioskID, Master_Kiosk.KioskName, Data_Kiosk_Header.YearFiscal;
```

after the code become like this :

```
DataKioskID |   KioskName   |YearFiscal |monthReport    |Advanta_Sales  |Agro_Sales |P12_Sales  |Advanta_Stocks |Agro_Stocks    |P12_Stocks |
AB0101061501|   Sarana Tani |2015       |6              |56         |23         |14         |12         |15         |12         |
AB0102061501|   Tani Lestari|2015       |6              |12         |14         |15         |15         |23         |14         |
```

Can anybody help me?,I wanna be like this.

```
|DataKioskID | KioskName   | YearFiscal | MonthReport |         Sales          |         Stock          |
|            |             |            |             | Advanta | Agro  | P12  | Advanta | Agro  | P12  |      
|AB0101061501| Sarana Tani |       2015 |           6 |      56 |     23|    14|      12 |     15|    12|
|AB0102061501| LestariTani |       2015 |           6 |      15 |     12|    14|      14 |     15|    16|
```

Here I give the DB to you can try what I mean:
[DB Source](http://www.4shared.com/zip/CEh1qpnGce/NewArmada.html)

Comment: I'm not sure it's SQL job to generate this kind of result. You may want to copy past to ms excel and format it. Or you can use a 3rd party report tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly what you want is not possible at least on query level because you have 2 level grouping...report is the answer
Furthermore in order to get the info as a "single" query you need the following
1st a cross tab query for sales

```
TRANSFORM Max(Data_Kiosk_Detail.Sales) AS MaxOfSales

SELECT Data_Kiosk_Header.DataKioskID
,Master_Kiosk.KioskName
,Data_Kiosk_Header.YearFiscal
,Data_Kiosk_Header.MonthReport AS monthReport
,"Sales" AS Info
FROM Master_Kiosk
INNER JOIN (
Data_Kiosk_Header INNER JOIN (
    Data_Kiosk_Detail INNER JOIN Master_Product ON Data_Kiosk_Detail.ProductID = Master_Product.ProductID
    ) ON Data_Kiosk_Header.DataKioskID = Data_Kiosk_Detail.DataKioskID
) ON Master_Kiosk.kioskid = Data_Kiosk_Header.KioskName
GROUP BY Data_Kiosk_Header.DataKioskID
,Master_Kiosk.KioskName
,Data_Kiosk_Header.YearFiscal
,Data_Kiosk_Header.MonthReport
,"Sales"
PIVOT Data_Kiosk_Detail.ProductID;
```

2nd a cross tab query for Stocks

```
TRANSFORM Max(Data_Kiosk_Detail.Stocks) AS MaxOfStocks

SELECT Data_Kiosk_Header.DataKioskID
,Master_Kiosk.KioskName
,Data_Kiosk_Header.YearFiscal
,Data_Kiosk_Header.MonthReport AS monthReport
,"Stocks" AS Info
FROM Master_Kiosk
INNER JOIN (
Data_Kiosk_Header INNER JOIN (
    Data_Kiosk_Detail INNER JOIN Master_Product ON Data_Kiosk_Detail.ProductID = Master_Product.ProductID
    ) ON Data_Kiosk_Header.DataKioskID = Data_Kiosk_Detail.DataKioskID
) ON Master_Kiosk.kioskid = Data_Kiosk_Header.KioskName
GROUP BY Data_Kiosk_Header.DataKioskID
,Master_Kiosk.KioskName
,Data_Kiosk_Header.YearFiscal
,Data_Kiosk_Header.MonthReport
,"Stocks"
PIVOT Data_Kiosk_Detail.ProductID;
```

Then you join them together with a union query

```
select * from MaxOfSales
UNION select * from MaxOfStocks;
```

Then you could use the above query to create a report to show what you need